# accessing public variable inside protected method

Tags: c#

I have `public class` and a `public variable` inside class.

```
public class Student 
{
    public string _firstName = null;

}
```

I have `protected method` in `Student` class where i am setting `_firstName` value

```
protected override void validate()
{

_firstName = "Test 1"
}
```

But, when i try to use `_firstName` value in another `protected method` of same class , it always gives null to me.

```
protected override string buildName()
{
    return String.Format("{0}_{1}", _firstName, _lastName);
}
```

Why? Am i missing some important concept here?

Comment: make sure `validate` is called before `buildName`, or call it inside buildName before using `_firstName`

Comment: The pieces of code you've shown could produce result you are looking for (as well all sorts of problems) - without [MCVE] it is not possible to say what is going wrong there.

Comment: Thanks Kazem. should be fine now.

Comment: Are you getting any build errors when running the code?

Comment: I have just got this code to work, by copying what you have. Can you post ALL of the code you are using in relation to this please? As it sems to work fine for me. Also in your validate() method there is no semicolon (;) at the end of the statement assigning a value to _firstName; just in case that is the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mis-reading this you should be setting the variable FullName in your method, not _firstName.

Comment: mistake from my side. I updated my question. kindly recheck.